# Do I need an audio interface to play only voice/keyboard?

Tags: recording, keyboard, sound, audio

I have a CASIO CTK-6200 and I've been testing its line outputs. Used a cable and connected to my mobo (Gigabyte 990XA UD3). The quality of audio is pretty decent. I'm going to buy a mic now, and since there are models with USB port, I was wondering if is it necessary to get an audio interface.

Of course there is the delay issue, but I'm not intending to play and sing at the same time, but to edit each part carefully.

So, should I spend money on an audio interface?

Comment: Deliberate duplicate of https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/42925/do-i-need-an-audio-interface-to-play-only-voice-keyboard on Sound StackExchange.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on whether you are recording to make money, or just for fun, whether you have lots or little money to spend on an AI, and whether you intend to buy a fantastic mic, a budget mic, or something in between.

I myself was about to purchase an audio interface to record audio to accompany my piano playing. However, I decided to buy a USB mic and am very happy with it. I purchased a Blue Snowball USB Mic, and have never looked back. If you have a spare USB port, I can certainly recommend getting such a mic, and saving a bit of cash as well!

Further, with the purchase of a Lightning-to-USB adapter or similar such dongle for other devices, I am able to use this Mic with my iPad and iPhone, whereas a non-USB mic might require a lot more setup and equipment to record on the go. The USB also ensures compatibility with almost all computers if travelling or in an unfamiliar setup.

However, if you intend on buying more mics, or more instruments with line-outs, then an audio interface could provide the added flexibility of being able to swap your mic for another or an instrument.

Comment: Also - keep in mind that USB mics are often very easy and simple to set up, which is great for beginners. However, an audio interface provides more immediate control, but also requires more knowledge to get just the right sound.

Answer (score 1):

You could get away without one.  You'll find life easier with one.  But get the mic, do some recording.  If you're getting results that satisfy you, leave well alone.  If not, come back and tell us what's lacking.  Sound quality?  Ease of use?  Then we can advise.

Note that strictly speaking you HAVE an audio interface, built into your computer.  And another one between the mic and its USB connection.